# Java: @NonNull for int?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm looking for `@NonNull` equivalent Java annotation for primitive data type. I know primitive data cannot be `null`, but I wasn't able to find an alternative.

What I'd like to achieve is logically equivalent to:

```
int mPageNumber;

public void updatePage(@NonNull final Integer nonNull) {
    mPageNumber = nonNull.intValue();
}
```

I tried:

```
int mPageNumber;

public void updatePage(@NonNull final int nonNull) {
    mPageNumber = nonNull;
}
```

And I get the following lint warning:

> Primitive type members cannot be annotated. This inspection reports
>   problems related to @Nullable and @NotNull annotations usage
>   configured in Constant conditions & exceptions inspection.

What can I put in place of `@NonNull` and `Integer` in `updatePage` method above, so that I can have `int` as an argument, not `Integer`?

Comment: Change the parameter type to `int`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can I ignore the lint warning?

Comment: Just remove the `@NonNull`. You don't need it. It's implicit with `int` that a `null` value is not possible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What if I want to make sure `nonNull` is previously initialized and receive a lint warning if not?

Comment: By definition, it has to be initialized with a non null value. It's a primitive.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If `@NonNull` can be used for primitive data type, why do I get the lint warning of above?

Comment: It's an annotation. There's no Java language construct that restricts whether it can annotate a reference type method parameter and not a primitive type method parameter. The warning you get is from your annotation post processor, which is telling you that there's no need to put `@NonNull` there because it's **impossible** for that variable to be `null`.

Comment: What would be the value for you to consider the integer null ? 0 ?

Comment: I think some frameworks like Spring have annotations to clamp primitives to ranges, but it has been awhile. But I can see the win under some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `mPageNumber` type to `Integer`.

As `int` type can not be `null`, but **`Integer`** can do.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, `int` itself doesn't need an annotation.

However, you might want to control where collections (including arrays) permit nulls. Primitive arrays can take an annotation on the square brackets, since the array itself is a reference type and can be null.

Here are some examples. Note that `List`s are more readable. You can also annotate the contents of `Map`s if you, e.g. don't want null keys.

```java
int noPossibleNullValue = 42;
// int noPossibleNullValue = null; // error
@NotNull Integer prohibitByAnnotation = 42;
prohibitByAnnotation = null; // warning
int @NotNull [] arrayOfInts = {1, 2, 3};
// arrayOfInts = {1, 2, null}; // error
arrayOfInts = null; // warning
int @NotNull [] @Nullable [] arrayOfArraysOfInts = {null, {3, 4, 5}};
arrayOfArraysOfInts = null; // warning
@Nullable List<@NotNull Integer> listOfIntegers = List.of(3, 4, 5);
listOfIntegers = List.of(3, 4, null); // warning
```

Recall that all collections, including arrays, are reference values, so they can be null even if their elements can't.

Here's a [demonstration of the syntax](https://godbolt.org/z/eEbven41f) on Godbolt, so you can verify for yourself that it compiles on all the versions of Java they support. If you want to use those annotations for real, you'd want something like [BeanValidation](https://beanvalidation.org/), or your IDE's [built-in annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) and checking facilities.

Comment: just want to know `int @NotNull []` syntax since which jdk version, I encounter compile error, on corretto-11 also jdk1.8

Comment: @VinceStyling I've added a link to Godbolt so you can play with it online.